# Force update of SideInput on updating Dataflow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam

I have a Dataflow pipeline running that fetches a configuration of active tenants (stored in GCS) and feeds it into an `ActiveTenantFilter` as a sideInput. The configuration is rarely updated, hence why I decided to re-deploy the pipeline, using the `--update` flag, whenever it is updated.

However, when using the update flag, the file is not fetched again, i.e., the state is maintained. Is it possible to enforce that this `PCollectionView` is updated whenever the pipeline is re-deployed?

[image: Pipeline Description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, when you `--update` a pipeline it will process new data but will not re-load old data.  It sounds like what you want is [slowly updating side inputs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LDY_CtsOJ8Y_zNv1QtkP6AGFrtzkj1q5EW_gSChOIvg/edit#heading=h.iluf68hiykcs) which unfortunately has not been implemented yet.  You could instead try draining and re-starting your pipeline.

Comment: In my case, the job was being launched by Terraform. Hence, it was not so straight forward to drain and re-start. In the end, I decided to fetch the config in the `@setup` method of the `FilterNonActive` tenants transform. As the setup is, in fact, re-executed when updating the pipeline. Will be keeping an eye on the updating side inputs progress. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @robertwb it almost seems like it is getting there with `PeriodicImpulse`, but I can't quite grok how to get it working locally..