# How to provide a slowly (every 12 hours) updated dictionary as a sideinput to another pipeline

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have a list of `api_key->account_id` mappings stored in a database that is used in our pipeline to enrich elements from a streaming pipeline. This list gets updated on a weekly basis, but I'd like to update it every 12-hour or so.

Reading the documentation [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/#slowly-updating-side-input-using-windowing) something like `PeriodicImpulse` seems close to what I want to do (although the empty example [above](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/#slowly-updating-global-window-side-inputs) sounds like precisely what I want to do - but does not seem to have been implemented yet according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62756137/force-update-of-sideinput-on-updating-dataflow-pipeline) stackoverflow post).

Using the example, I attempted to write a simple test to see how it actually pairs items. The below code seems to do what I want, but there are some really confusing parts of it:

1. `start_timestamp` defaults to `Timestamp.now()`, but it fails with the following error if one does not specify the argument:

   `TypeError: Cannot interpret Timestamp(1599140525.255833) <class'apache_beam.utils.timestamp.Timestamp'> as seconds.`

   The fix is to specifically provide the argument as `start_timestamp=time.time()`
2. if the `stop_timestamp` is not provided, the Pipeline runs forever, even though the `main_input` is done sending items

   I don't think it is a bug, but I don't really know how to circumvent this in, will it ever stop? What if I start `draining` the pipeline? Will I have to do that manually?
3. If `stop_timestamp` is provided, no output seems to be produced until the pipeline has run for at least `(stop_timestamp - start_timestamp) - fire_interval`).

   This could of course just be the TestPipeline failing to write as it processes, but when testing I printed the final timestamp I saw, and it matched the timestamp in the pipeline, which precisely matched when the pipeline was done running, not 50 to 30 seconds earlier, when I expected it to be.

I think I expected there to be some output after 10 seconds (due to the windowing) and then have the pipeline end pretty much at that point.

Does anyone have any insights here?

Example:

```py
def run():
    def pair_account_ids(
        api_key: str, account_ids: Dict[str, str]
    ) -> Optional[Tuple[str, str, int]]:
        if api_key not in account_ids:
            return None

        return (api_key, account_ids[api_key], int(time.time()))

    def echo(elm) -> Dict[str, str]:
        print(elm)
        return elm

    def api_keys(elm) -> Dict[str, str]:
        return {"<api_key_1>": "<account_id_1>", "<api_key_2>": "<account_id_2>"}

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(streaming=True)

    with beam.Pipeline(
        options=pipeline_options, runner=beam.runners.DirectRunner()
    ) as p:
        side_input = (
            p
            | "PeriodicImpulse"
            >> PeriodicImpulse(
                start_timestamp=time.time(),
                stop_timestamp=time.time() + 60,
                fire_interval=10,
                apply_windowing=True,
            )
            | "api_keys" >> beam.Map(api_keys)
        )

        main_input = (
            p
            | "MpImpulse"
            >> beam.Create(["<api_key_1>", "<api_key_2>", "<unknown_api_key>"])
            | "MapMpToTimestamped"
            >> beam.Map(lambda src: TimestampedValue(src, time.time()))
            | "WindowMpInto" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(10))
        )

        result = (
            main_input
            | "Pair with AccountIDs"
            >> beam.Map(
                pair_account_ids, account_ids=beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(side_input)
            )
            | "filter" >> beam.Filter(lambda x: x is not None)
            | "echo 2"
            >> beam.Map(lambda x: print(f"{int(time.time())}: {x}"))
        )
    print(f"done:  {int(time.time())}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Output (taken from my unittest):

```
test_side_input (not_test.TestE2E) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 50.115s

OK
1599147476: ('<api_key_1>', '<account_id_1>', 1599147476)
1599147476: ('<api_key_2>', '<account_id_2>', 1599147476)
done:  1599147476
```

**Update with Daniel's suggestions**

```py
        window_size = 5
        trigger_interval = 30
        side_input = beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(
            p
            | "trigger pipeline" >> beam.Create([None])
            | "define schedule"
            >> beam.Map(
                lambda _: (
                    0,  # timestamp.Timestamp.now().__float__(),
                    60,  # timestamp.Timestamp.now().__float__() + 30.0,
                    trigger_interval,  # fire_interval
                )
            )
            | "GenSequence" >> PeriodicSequence()
            | "api_keys" >> beam.ParDo(ApiKeys())
            | "ApplyWindowing"
            >> beam.WindowInto(
                beam.window.FixedWindows(trigger_interval),
                trigger=AfterProcessingTime(window_size - 1),
                accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING,
            )
        )
```

I am getting this issue now when combining it with the main pipeline (I've updated the `trigger_interval` to be distinctly different from the main pipeline):

```sh
TypeError: argument of type 'EmptySideInput' is not iterable [while running 'Pair with AccountIDs']
```

It looks like the SideInput is empty when it attempts to process an element from the main pipeline?

Answer (score 4):

1. That definitely seems like a bug, probably worth reporting.
2. This seems like intended behavior. The way `PeriodicImpulse` works is as a transform that emits elements at specified time intervals. Due to the way the beam model works, this transform has no knowledge of where its outputs are going or that it's a side input being consumed, so it has no way of stopping execution once its consumers transforms are finished.
3. This is a bug in your code. When you set the periodic impulses, you set a timestamp using `time.time()` directly in your construction code, so the timestamp grabbed is when the pipeline is being constructed. But when you map timestamps to your elements, you use a lambda for your DoFn, so that lambda gets called and the elements are given a timestamp during execution time. Since execution time is long after pipeline construction time, all your elements will only be placed in the last window emitted by `PeriodicImpulse`, but it takes some time for the watermark to catch up to that window and for it to get output.

The solution for a unit test is to adjust the way timestamps are used. Test it with explicitly defined timestamps instead of `time.time()` and you should see everything lining up correctly.

For actual execution code, it depends on the nature of your timestamps. If your timestamps are part of your elements when they're read (like timestamps on some database), then you should be fine simply by making sure the space of possible timestamps being read represented in your PeriodicImpulse.

On the other hand, if you're assigning `time.time()` to elements as you do in this example, you won't really need to change anything. If your windows are expected to be 12 hours long then even with the delay between construction and execution time, your first few elements will still read from the first window just fine.

**Edit**: A key detail I forgot is that if you have a side input with a significantly larger window than your main input, then you will need to set up some triggers to fire early window panes. Otherwise, if windows are only fired end-of-window, then all your main input elements will remain unprocessed until the entire 12 hour window is ready to fire. To fire windows early, you will want to set up some [triggers](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#triggers). (You may also need a Reshuffle transform before sending it as a side input for the triggers to take effect. I'm not sure how triggers interact with side inputs.)

Comment: Thank you for looking at the code!

Concerning your solution to 2), how would you provide explicit timestamps for the start and stop, just hardcoding values to be somewhere around  10 seconds in the future?

Comment: Due to the issue in 1) I can't provide the `start_time=Timestamp.now()` value - I am unsure of how to just say "run forever, from right now - trigger immediately" with `Timestamps`?

The elements from the `main_input` will.be streaming in live from a PubSub and have an implicit timestamp in production, and I am thinking of a 60 second window for those - will that work alright with a 12 hour `fire_interval` for the impulse (and should I use the `apply_windowing=True` thing to make that happen)? Will the singleton sideinput match up alright with those values?

Comment: I'm still struggling with grokking how to set the start_time and stop_time in production such that it runs forever, triggering every `X` hours and merging with whatever every window in between from the `main_pipeline` - so frustrating..

Comment: For the test, you can set hardcoded values for timestamps. Just integers like 0, 10, 60, etc. That way you will always have deterministic behavior and can see exactly how the windowing is behaving.

Comment: For your normal usage, using start_time=time.time() should work, and the rest of your code should work fine. To explain what's happening, if time.time() uses the construction-time timestamp, and PubSub uses the implicit timestamp from when you read the message, then the element timestamps will begin at a delay from the timestamps where the interval windows begin. (Ex. if execution starts ten minutes after construction, then the window will begin at timestamp 0 min. and your first element will have timestamp 10 min). However, your interval windows are hours long, so a small delay is no problem.

Comment: @Paddie Also I added an edit to the answer, because I realized you might need triggering on the large time windows to get your pipeline working like you expect.

Comment: does it need to be an accumulating trigger? A lot of this is a bit new to me, so if you could point to some code that does something like this I might be able to grok it a bit better. To the previous post about just adding integers, I don't think I realised that the start_time etc. were values that were relative to the start of the pipeline.. This makes it a lot easier to test then, thank you!

Comment: So, will the trigger need to trigger at the same frequency sa the `main_input`?

Comment: Based on the nature of your side input, you probably want an accumulating trigger, and you'll probably want it to fire at the same frequency as the main input or faster to avoid delaying the main input.

Comment: I updated the post with the changes I made (it makes it easier to talk about). Does what I wrote reflect what you are suggesting?

Comment: This subject seems to be getting a bit involved for a SO question. You should consider taking this to [user@ mailing list](https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/) where you can get help from users more knowledgeable than me.

For your question: You can probably replace the Create with an Impulse transform. I was also thinking the periodic sequence would generate 12-hour elements/windows. Otherwise it looks good, not sure why you're getting an empty side input.

Comment: It is, thank you for your patience! I did not know of the mailinglist